# Are squared loadings and squared distances the same in Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, eigenvalues

I read online that:

Eigenvalue: Represents the variance explained by the principal component. It equals both the sum of squared loadings for that component and the sum of squared projections of data points onto that component.

Is this true? I also read that an eigenvalue (geometrically) is the average sum of squared distances, and also read that it is the sum of squared distances (not average).